# How does a gas grill starter spark work?

Tags: voltage, generator

On some gas grills, there is a button you push which creates a spark to ignite the gas (propane, natural gas etc.)

My questions are probably pretty simple:

How does the button create the spark?

What voltage is this spark?

Comment: See also http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/11816

Comment: There are a different type where you press the button, hold it down and get a series of sparks. How do these work and what are they called?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Almost all are piezo-electric. Check [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piezo_ignition) for info:

Piezo ignition is a type of ignition that is used in portable camping stoves, gas grills and some lighters. It consists of a small, spring-loaded hammer which, when a button is pressed, hits a crystal of PZT or quartz crystal. Quartz is piezoelectric, which means that it creates a voltage when deformed. This sudden forceful deformation produces a high voltage and subsequent electrical discharge, which ignites the gas.

And as Christopher Biggs commented:

> the dielectric strength of dry air is about 33kV/cm, so if the spark jumps 2mm it has to be at least 6600v

Comment: Great answer.   As for the voltage, the dielectric strength of dry air is about 33kV/cm, so if the spark jumps 2mm it has to be at least 6600v.

Comment: Is there any insight as to why this method isn't used in place of spark plugs in cars?  My first thought when playing with my bbq starter was wondering how they could possibly fit an ignition coil and contact breaker in such a tiny box all on a 1.5 volt AA battery.  Thanks for clearing this up :)

Comment: not a good topic for conversation in comments (better in chat) but a major drawback is the amount of physical deformation required, leading to failure.